# IIS web application connection to Oracle DBMS using DoD-issued PKI certificates

Tags: asp.net, oracle, ssl, iis, pki

We have an asp.net web application that currently connects to an Oracle 11g database with a single application account for all users ( user security is handled at the application layer ).  We have requirements to convert this single application account from username/password to pki authentication for connection to the Oracle database.

*Environment*: 
Windows 2008 R2
IIS 7.5
asp.net
Oracle 11g (also on windows 2008 R2)

Can anyone provide guidance on how we should configure the account on the Oracle DB, Windows, and the connection string in web.config to make this possible?

I've included the pertinent portion of the actual requirement below:

---

Rule Title: Processes (services, applications, etc.) that connect to the DBMS independently of individual users, must use valid, current DoD-issued PKI certificates for authentication to the DBMS.

Just as individual users must be authenticated, and just as they must use PKI-based authentication, so must any processes that connect to the DBMS.

The DoD standard for authentication of a process or device communicating with another process or device is the presentation of a valid, current, DoD-issued Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) certificate that has previously been verified as Trusted by an administrator of the other process or device.

This applies both to processes that run on the same server as the DBMS and to processes running on other computers.

---

Comment: What is the type of application that is going to connect to to Oracle DBMS? Is it a WCF service or ASP.NET or something else? Have you seen this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/network.920/a96582/authuser.htm

Comment: I'll look at that doc, but I've seen several that talk high level describing what is available, but I'm looking for a "how to" if available.

We have an application that's made up of several ASP.NET Web Forms solutions. Currently each solution has a connection string in it's web.config (or app.config) file. We connect directly to the DB using that connection string. Our new requirement is to remove that connection string and use PKI authentication to access the DB.

Comment: I have the exactly same requirements, assuming that you did implemented could you please provide the steps?